# Pygame pokemon style text display

Tags: python, pygame

I've already seen some tutorials one here to place text onto a pygame window delayed so that it appears asif it were in a pokemon game. However I'm having trouble doing this straight to a window rather than inserting it into a 'rect' shape. The program does not display any errors and runs fine however the text does not show on screen either.

```
def display_text_animation(string):   #Here is the function for animating the text
text = ''
for i in range(len(string)):
    text += string[i]
    text_surface = font.render(text, True, BLACK)
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.time.wait(100)


def intro():
    gameDisplay = displayBox()


    progBg1 = pygame.image.load("introScr.png")
    gameDisplay.blit(progBg1, (0,0))
    display_text_animation('Hello World!')     #here is where I call the text to appear.
```

Comment: which part exactly is rendering the text? I don't see you referencing `text` anywhere.

Comment: @Jerome Indefenzo sorry I forgot to add the render line. My bad

Comment: so... does it work now?

Answer (score 3):

You call `font.render`, which returns a `Surface` that you store in the `text_surface` variable.

But you don't do anything with this new `Surface`. You have to blit it onto the display `Surface` before calling `pygame.display.update()`.

Comment: Apologies but how would I go about doing that? Thank you fro the help @sloth